# Show that $\Bbb Z_{12}/\langle[3]_{12}\rangle \cong \Bbb Z_p$ for some $p \in \Bbb N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

> Let $\langle[3]_{12}\rangle$ be the normal subgroup of $\Bbb Z_{12}$ generated  by $[3]_{12}$. Show that $$\Bbb Z_{12}/\langle[3]_{12}\rangle \cong \Bbb Z_p$$ for some $p \in \Bbb N$.

My hunch is that $p=11$ as the group $\Bbb Z_{12}/\langle[3]_{12}\rangle$ identifies $3$ with $0$ and thus we're left with $11$ elements.

I don't know what the map $f: \Bbb Z_{12}/\langle[3]_{12}\rangle \to \Bbb Z_{11}$ should be. If I take $a + [3]_{12} \longmapsto [a]_{11}$ I don't know wheter this satisfies the requirements?

Comment: You know what a subgroup is. Let us write $3=[3]_{12}$. What about $3+3$, or $3-3$? or $3+3+3$? Are these elements in the subgroup, too? What are the axioms for a subgroup? And note that $| \Bbb Z_{12}/H|=12/d$, where $d=|H|$. So $12/d=11$ is impossible.

Comment: Alright! I think that $p = 3$ then?

Comment: Indeed, $d=4$, so $\frac{12}{4}=3$. Note that there is only one group of order $3$, up to isomorphism.

Comment: What is the intuition in this problem? The group $\Bbb Z_{12}/\langle[3]_{12}\rangle$ is the one where I indetify all sums $a + [3]_{12}$ with $0$?

Comment: The idea is to get more intuition of quotient groups by many explicit examples. So write down all possible subgroups $H$ of $\Bbb Z_{12}$ and compute the quotients.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of $H:=\langle [3]_{12}\rangle$ is four; this follows from $H$ being cyclic (as $G:=\Bbb Z_{12}$ is cyclic) and

$$\begin{align}
0[3]_{12}&=[0]_{12}, \\
1[3]_{12}&=[3]_{12},\\
2[3]_{12}&=[6]_{12},\\
3[3]_{12}&=[9]_{12},\\
4[3]_{12}&=[0]_{12}.
\end{align}$$

Therefore, by Lagrange's Theorem, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lvert G/H\rvert&=\lvert G\rvert/\lvert H\rvert\\
&=12/4\\
&=3.
\end{align}$$

But the only group of order three is $\Bbb Z_3$ up to isomorphism.